# can't access the value of a pointer inside a returned struct [C]

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

I'm pretty new to the C language, and I'm struggling with pointers (I used to program in Python). So, I have a two file project, the main one (.c) and another header (.h). I declared in the header one a custom type point_t and some function, such as p_middle, which calculated the coordinate of the middle point starting from two points. I tested out the function in the header file and there it works, but when I try to use it in the source file it doesn't. The structure point_t is declared as follows:

```
typedef struct point {

    char p_name; // stores the point name as a single character
    short p_dim; // stores the point dimension (it can be omitted and calculated using p_dimension)
    double *p_start_coords; // pointer to the first coordinate of coordinate list
    double *p_end_coords; // pointer to the last coordinate of coordinate list

} point_t;
```

and the function p_middle has a declaration that looks like:

```
point_t p_middle (point_t p1, point_t p2) {

    point_t p_middle;
    // p_middle initialization

    // some code here

    return p_middle

}
```

so in the source file I tried creating two points as:

```
point_t p1;
point_t p2;

double coord_set1[4] = {0, 2, 3, 4};
double coord_set2[4] = {3, 1, 6, 4};

p1.p_start_coords = &coord_set1[0];
p1.p_end_coords = &coord_set1[3];
p1.p_name = 'A';

p2.p_start_coords = &coord_set2[0];
p2.p_end_coords = &coord_set2[3];
p2.p_name = 'B';
```

I then tried to do in the source file:

```
p_m = p_middle(p1, p2);

printf("middle point of p1p2: (%f, ", *p_m.p_start_coords);
++p_m.p_start_coords;
printf("%f, ", *p_m.p_start_coords);
++p_m.p_start_coords;
printf("%f, ", *p_m.p_start_coords);
++p_m.p_start_coords;
printf("%f)\n", *p_m.p_start_coords);
```

But, when I try to run the program it doesn't work, it prints rundom - I think - numbers. Any idea for solutions?

P.S. Excuse my English, I'm still practising it.

Comment: It looks like you are assigning pointers to arrays that only exist within the function. Those pointers become dangling after the function returns, as the arrays no longer exist

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your `p_middle(point_t p1, point_t p2)` function is implemented but I am sure that your `p_start_coords` pointer is pointing to wrong address. I wrote it like this just for testing, and it compiled, worked without any problem:

```
point_t p_middle (point_t p1, point_t p2) {

    point_t p_middle;
    p_middle.p_name = 'M';
    p_middle.p_dim = 100;
    p_middle.p_start_coords = p1.p_start_coords;
    p_middle.p_end_coords = p2.p_end_coords;

    return p_middle;
}
```

Try to assign valid address to your pointers